# Как можно найти элемент по двум атрибутам?

Tags: javascript

Хочу найти элемент, у которого есть `data-x=1` и `data-y=1`

Все эти способы не работают:

```
document.querySelector("div[data-x=1 data-y=1]");
document.querySelector("div[data-x=1data-y=1]");
document.querySelector("div[data-x=1][data-y=1]");
```

Comment: Кавычки забыли поставить `document.querySelector('div[data-x="1"][data-y="1"]')`

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо большое